# How do I know im capable of doing mathematical sciences for a college degree?

Tags: soft-question

I felt this is the best place to ask, what does it take to study math at college level? I know you're probably saying you have to be a genius or work hard, I'm willing to work hard...I did three years of an engineering/physics course and I got top marks in but the maths was very practical.....I just worry that no matter how much work I put in I still won't be able to to get through it

Please advise...how did you guys know that you were able for it?

Comment: No point in deciding to get a degree in math without testing out some classes first (if possible). It sounds like you're pretty comfortable with the applied math that you've seen, so try to get into some more abstract classes and see what you think. If you like the classes and are willing to work hard then you'll most likely be fine-- no reasonable professor expects a room full of geniuses

Comment: Avoid using tags in titles, as tags in the post are already sufficient.

Comment: I doubt anyone is saying you have to be a genius.  One does not even have to be a genius to do good research, much less to get good grades in undergrad math.  The biggest hurdle is likely to be your first exposure to proof-based courses such as real analysis and abstract algebra.  A lot of people struggle with the transition into writing proofs and coming up with proofs.  On the other hand, a lot of people think that's when math starts to get really fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the grades/qualifications/prerequisites to be accepted into a math college course, then you have the grades/qualifications/prerequisites to accepted into a math college course ;-).

*looks at your other questions...*  I think the fact that you're self-motivated to teach yourself group-theory and concepts such as closure is enough evidence for me that you'd do well.

I got a BSc in Maths at a well-regarded UK institution.  Most of my classmates didn't end up as professional mathematicians - myself included.

I say if it interests you, then go for it!

Comment: Thank you youve really boosted my confidence....I actually spent a summer studying maths for kicks...perhaps I should look at this as good evidence...thanks again

Comment: @MichaelO'Driscoll FWIW at the secondary/high school level I had a pretty inflated sense of my teenage self and thought I was some kind of mathematical genius.  A couple of years of university-level maths soon knocked some humble pie into me and I realised I am just a normal human being ;-)  Nevertheless I was able to enjoy, complete and earn my Maths BSc.